# file not found after upload in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, web

I would like to upload some files to my server. So far, they have been successfully stored in a MySQL database, but the problem is that the uploaded file is not found in a folder that is located on the server.

Here's my code:

```
$dir = $filename;
    $target_dir = "file/$dir/";
    if( is_dir($target_dir) === false )
    {
        mkdir($target_dir);
    }

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $formatfile = array('pdf');
    $filetest= $_FILES['filetest']['name'];
    $x = explode('.', $filetest);
    $existence= strtolower(end($x));
    $pdfsize = $_FILES['filetest']['size'];
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['filetest']['tmp_name'];    


    if(in_array($existence, $formatfile) === true){

            if($pdfsize < 1044070){         
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "$target_dir.$filetest");
            }
        }
    }
 $sql = "INSERT INTO test (filename) VALUES ('$filetest')";
```

Is there anything I missed?

Comment: did you get any errors from `php`?

Comment: Check with error_reporting(1) and check target_dir.

Comment: no , the name of the file that I uploaded successfully entered in the database but when I open the folder where to save the file , the file does not exist.

Comment: yes because of your target url is not correct.

Comment: Why is noone using `__DIR__`, `realpath()`, etc. ? Consider using those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change `$formatfile = array('pdf')` to `$formatfile = array('.pdf'=>'application/pdf');`

Comment: Please explain why he should "try this".

Answer (score 0):

$dir = $filename;   Whis is vlaue of **$filename** ?

please use like this. 
$dir = '/var/www/uploads/';

```
if(in_array($existence, $formatfile)){
            if($pdfsize < 1044070){         
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "$target_dir.$filetest");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

whenever you are uploading a file.try the full path.

```
<?php

$dir = $filename;
$target_dir = dirname(__FILE__).'/file/'.$dir.'/';
if (is_dir($target_dir) === false) {
    mkdir($target_dir);
}
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $formatfile = array('pdf');
    $filetest = $_FILES['filetest']['name'];
    $x = explode('.', $filetest);
    $existence = strtolower(end($x));
    $pdfsize = $_FILES['filetest']['size'];
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['filetest']['tmp_name'];
    if (in_array($existence, $formatfile) === true) {
        if ($pdfsize < 1044070) {
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $target_dir.$filetest);
        }
    }
}
$sql = 'INSERT INTO test (filename) VALUES ('.$filetest.')';
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$dir = $filename;
    $target_dir = "file/$dir/";
    if( is_dir($target_dir) === false )
    {
        mkdir($target_dir);
    }

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $formatfile = array('pdf');
    $filetest= $_FILES['filetest']['name'];
    $x = explode('.', $filetest);
    $existence= strtolower(end($x));
    $pdfsize = $_FILES['filetest']['size'];
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['filetest']['tmp_name'];    


    if(in_array($existence, $formatfile) === true){

            if($pdfsize < 1044070){         
                //Remove ""
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $target_dir.$filetest);
                //If file upload then and then execute query.
                $sql = "INSERT INTO test (filename) VALUES ('$filetest')";
            }else{
                 //Fire error
            }
        }else{
           //Fire error
        }
    }else{
         //Fire error
    }
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are not helpful.

Comment: In each and every changes i just add comment.

Comment: Should use early returns like in this gist: https://gist.github.com/atmoz/855ee294635ab1e649fe